# How to join a sf map data with tibble data using full_join?

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to join map data from rnaturalearth with a tibble.

Here is a dput of a chunk of my tibble:

```
structure(list(iso3_code = c("AFG", "AFG", "ALB", "ALB", "DZA", 
"ASM"), country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa"), item = c("Maize", "Sugar cane", 
"Maize", "Soybeans", "Maize", "Sugar cane"), value = c(106670, 
25421, 391104, 744, 4142, 30)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf")  
world_filtered = world %>% 
    select(country = name_long, iso3_code = iso_a3, geometry) %>%
    filter(!is.na(iso3_code)) %>% 
    filter(country != "Antarctica") 

map = full_join(world_filtered, country_data, by = "iso3_code")
```

I get this error:

```
Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `geometry` is a `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON/sfc` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I know I have run this code earlier and it worked. I just made some updates recently and maybe that could have affected this code. Would appreciate some help if someone knows what is going on here.

Comment: Your code works for me. Make sure you have loaded the required libraries `library(rgeos)`,  `library(rnaturalearth)`, `library(sf)`, `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: I tried loading all those packages but I still get the same error messages. I have tried to restart R too but that didn't work either. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I guess I also have `library(sp)` loaded. Otherwise, my only thought is that it's somewhere in the full version of `country_data`.

Comment: I also tried using this small chunk and got the same error.

Comment: Are you using R studio? Try running R from the command line and installing the packages fresh and see if the issue persists?

Answer (score 8):

I also have encountered this problem recently.

This is because `tidyverse` (base on `tibble`) can't recognize `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON/sfc` object.

The solution is:

```
library(sf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: See my comment below

If you've updated/installed the `tibble` package since June 2019, that might be the issue. I had a similar problem with doing a spatial join and came across a tidyverse GitHub issue where [gregmacfarlane surmised that this issue is caused by the newest version of tibble](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3927#issuecomment-618688932). Sure enough, after installing tibble version 2.1.3, I was able to do a spatial join. Previously I had installed version 3.0.1. I installed the older version using its url from the CRAN repository:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tibble/tibble_2.1.3.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Actually, a better way that [I've come across on GitHub](https://github.com/walkerke/tidycensus/issues/248#issuecomment-623810368) may be to update R rather than going back to and old version of tibble. I was able to do a join after updating to R 4.0.0; previously I was on version 3.5.2. I'm not adding this in the answer yet because I am unsure of your R version, and I don't have enough reputation to comment on the quesiton.